# SWING set size cursor

Tags: java, swing, cursor

So I've searched for many many many hours and tbh I do not understand ppls answers on how to change size of the cursor, anyone who could give me a clear "explenation". My code is shown below(part of it) what I want is to resize the cursor so it's possible to see what it is (if it's even possible)?

PS. I've tried the getBestCursorSize and BufferedImage but without luck.

in advance thx :)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
          Toolkit toolkitPatrol = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
      Image patrol = toolkitPatrol.getImage("Patrol.png");
      Dimension patSize = toolkitPatrol.getBestCursorSize(64, 64);

      this.patrolBoat = toolkitPatrol.createCustomCursor(patrol, hotspot, "Patrol");
if (e.getSource() == horizontal)
      {
         String selected = (String) horizontal.getSelectedItem();
         if (selected.equals("Patrol boat (2)"))
         {
            setCursor(patrolBoat);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: To my knowledge certain operating systems, such as windows, limits the size of cursors.

Comment: Would there be some other way to do this maybe? Cuse I'm totally blank at the moment :(

Comment: Well what will this cursor be on? Could you draw a cursor image on the jframe or applet instead?

Comment: Well the point was to make the classic battleship game, each time a player would choose the ship from a combobox the cursor changes to the ship. Not sure how to put pics here :P, totally new on stack xD

Comment: If you are using standard 2d graphics you could use a mouse listener and manually draw the cursor.

Comment: Ohhhh okay, thx a lot :), didn't think of that/ didn't know exactly how that worked :)